# Swap right command with right alt/option on external bluetooth keyboard

Tags: snow-leopard, keyboard

I can swap/remap (only) the right command with right alt using [Keyremap4macbook](http://www.pqrs.org/tekezo/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) for the built in Macbook keyboard, but would the same be possible for the Apple's external Bluetooth keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work at least on my Apple Wireless Keyboard. KeyRemap4MacBook should work with most external keyboards that don't have their own drivers.